# Make Gerrit always reject a commit

Tags: git, gerrit

While working on a new feature, I often commit changes that aren't part of the feature itself, but are useful at the time (for example, small changes to make my work easier to test).

The `commit-msg` hook automatically adds a `Change-Id` to every new commit, including my temporary ones. This leaves me in a state where I could accidentally push my branch to Gerrit, including the temporary commits.

Is there a way to 'taint' a commit so that attempting to push it (accidentally) to Gerrit will always fail?

Answer (score 1):

If `git commit --amend` is used to change the commit message, and the `Change-Id` line is removed, the `commit-msg` hook will add it back again.

Instead a `Change-Id` line is needed that:

- The `commit-msg` hook will treat as valid, so that it doesn't attempt to replace it or add another.
- Gerrit will reject.

The `commit-msg` hook looks for a line matching the regex `^Change-Id:` so as long as those characters are present (up to and including the colon) a new `Change-Id` won't be added.

```
This commit can't be pushed to Gerrit.

Change-Id:
```

Gerrit [firstly requires](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/v2.12.2/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/git/validators/CommitValidators.java#228) a `Change-Id` to match the regex `^I[0-9a-f]{8,}.*$`, so anything that fails to match this will be rejected by Gerrit with the message `missing or invalid Change-Id line format in commit message footer`:

```
Change-Id: blah
Change-Id: I000
Change-Id: I1234567
```

For new changes, Gerrit [subsequently requires](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/v2.12.2/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/git/ReceiveCommits.java#1631) a `Change-Id` to match `^I[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$` so in fact anything shorter than 40 characters will be rejected with the message `invalid Change-Id`:

```
Change-Id: I12345678
Change-Id: I012345678901234567890123456789012345678
```